# How to pass list of QBrush Objects to remote process in pyqtgraph

Tags: plot, multiprocessing, pickle, pyqtgraph

I'm new to pyqtgraph and really stuck with this problem. I'm developing a simulator for that I need a plotting library which is fast. So found pyqtgraph and it seems to be amazing.

I want to move plotting task to a separate process using pyqtgraph multiprocessing library so as to enhance performance. My simulation required different colors for different points hence I need to pass a QBrush object list to plot method. Everything is working fine locally but when I'm trying to pass QBrush object list to remote process i'm getting this error.

```
TypeError: can't pickle QBrush objects
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to pass the keyword dictionary for input to `mkBrush`. The dictionary would be pickleable.